# Evaluate the integral by interpreting it in terms of areas (using summation expressions)

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the integral by interpreting it in terms of areas (using summation expressions).

a. $\int_{-3}^1 \left(1 + \sqrt{9-x^2}\right)dx$

b. $\int_0^1 |2x − 1|dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

For the first integral, set $y=1+\sqrt{9-x^2}$. Squaring, you obtain the equation of a circle:
$$x^2+(y-1)^2=9$$
with centre $(0,1)$ and radius $3$. Therefore the integral represents the area of circular sector, for which there's a simple formula. You just have to find the initial and the final angles.

For the second integral, graph the function $|2x-1|$.

Comment: Thankyou I still dont quite understand most of the topic in calculus but still thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

Hint: a. Let $y=1+\sqrt{9-x^2}$. Then $y\ge1$ and $x^2+(y-1)^2=3^2$ and hence the graph of $y=1+\sqrt{9-x^2}$ for $-3\le x\le 1$ is a part of a circle centered a $(0,1)$ with radius $3$.

b. Let $y=|2x-1$. The graph is a "V" shape.

Comment: Thankyou I still dont quite understand most of the topic in calculus but still thankyou very much